# Jasmine - test function invoking variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am trying to test a scenario when a service method is invoked through a local variable within an angular controller.

In this situation, when the items array is 0, a create new item modal would be triggered through the modal service.

Controller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('Item', Item);

    //items is resolved through the ui-router resolve
    //items contains a array of item objects. Will be an empty array if there are no items for that user

    Item.$inject = ['items', 'modalService'];

    function Item(items, modalService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.items = items;
        vm.newItemModal = modalService.newItemModal;

        if (vm.items !== undefined) {
            if (vm.items.length === 0) {
                vm.newItemModal();
            }
        }
    }

})();
```

**vm.newItemModal(**) triggers the new item modal to be displayed. However, how do I test this scenario in jasmine?

Test so far:

```
describe('Controller: Item', function(){
    var scope, 
    ctrl, 
    items, 
    modalService,
    mockItems = [{ name: 'item1', desc:'desc1'}, { name: 'item2', desc:'desc2'}];

    //mocking the modalService
    beforeEach(function(){
        module(function($provide){
            modalService = {
                newItemModal: function(){
                    return;
                }
            };
            $provide.value('modalService', modalService);
        });

    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, $controller) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('Item as item', {
            $scope: scope,
            items: mockItems
        });
    }));

    it('should verify the vm object', function(){
        expect(scope.item.newItemModal).toBeDefined();
        expect(scope.item.items).toEqual(mockItems);
    });

    //Separate test-suite as items is initialised with an empty array
    describe('new item modal', function(){
        beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, $controller) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller('Item as item', {
            $scope: scope,
            items: []
        });

        it('should open a new item modal', function(){
            //returns 0
            console.log('Items length', scope.items.length);
            spyOn(scope.item, 'newItemModal').and.callThrough();
            //testing this assertion fails
            expect(scope.item.newItemModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    }));
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the following line is executed:

```
spyOn(scope.item, 'newItemModal').and.callThrough();
```

The controller has already been created and it's code executed.

You need to set up your spy before the controller is created.

Example:

```
var createController;

beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, $controller) {
  $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  scope = $rootScope.$new();

  createController = function() {
    $controller('Item as item', {
      $scope: scope,
      items: []
    });
  };
}));

it('should open a new item modal', function() {
  spyOn(modalService, 'newItemModal').and.callThrough();
  createController();
  expect(scope.item.newItemModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Note that you can not spy on `scope.item` since it isn't created until the controll is, so you will have to spy on the `modalService` instead.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/y0vzfaqDSuuCuPVwdybq?p=preview